# char* string substract function throws exception

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

I'm working on my own string class called PString, I have this function that
finds a specific character, like 6, and now I have this function called substr short fo substract, where I want to substract from 0 to [insertnumber].
the way I'm trying to call this is by doing this:

```
PString string;
int to = 0;
string = "A string = a string"; // lol
string.find('=', to);
string.substr(to);
```

My find function is fine and works 100%, but my substr function doens't work.
Here is my substr function:

```
void PString::substr(int to) {
    char* temp = new char[255];
    temp = this->c_str();
    for (int i = 0; i < to; i++) {
        temp[i] = ' ';
    }
}
```

this->c_str() just returns the current string the object is holding, this is to
prevent failure, but I cannot get past the first for loop, temp[i] = ' ' just throws a exception and I'm completely clueless as to why.

Oh and yes, I know my function isn't deleting temp and more stuff, but this just hasn't been implemented as I'm trying to get the for loop to work first.

Edit fixed by makign a few more functions (makign a new PString from a already created PString)
Also used memcpy instead of just doing a simple equals operator

Comment: "substr" is "substring", not "substract". And it returns a *new* string.

Comment: try `strcpy(temp,c_str());`...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment

Comment: @OskarDahlberg Why are you creating a new string if your goal is to *remove* characters?  It's so wrong in a lot of ways.

Comment: How is the line `string = "A string = a string";` implemented? Do you simply save just a pointer to the provided string or do you make a copy of that string?

Comment: `char* temp = new char[255]; temp = this->c_str();`  Why not `PString temp(*this);`  If your class has no copy constructor, add it.  It is worthless if you can't create a PString from an existing PString.

Comment: Memory leak on the 2nd line of the function. No check that 'to' is < length of `c_str()` (or even that c_str isn't null).  Expected behavior is a mystery given the function name...

Comment: @OskarDahlberg You wouldn't have the mistake in your code if you had written a copy constructor (which **all** string classes should have).  You would have simply created another `PString` object, as my previous comment shows.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The problem can be caused by rewriting the read-only string literal. To recognize that we have to know whether a copy is made in the constructor.

Comment: @diask There are a lot of problems with the code.

Answer (score 1):

The first obvious mistake you're doing here is this:

```
char* temp = new char[255];
temp = this->c_str();
```

You allocate memory then you're copying the value of a pointer. So first you're getting a memory leak and second depending on your implementation of `c_str()` you are copying the address of something you're not supposed to change (`std::string`'s `c_str()` returns `const char*`).

This is because the actual implementation of a `std::string` doesn't require a heap-allocated array actually and some implementations actually store a small array internally for short strings.

So if you actually want to make a new string, the best thing to do would be to copy the memory instead:

```
char* temp = new char[this->size()];
memcpy(temp,this->c_str(),this->size()) //I assume 8-bit string, change if you use widechars
```

Then you return a new string using `temp` to initialize it.